# Add ufl connector to internal patch antenna

Tags: gps, pcb-antenna

Hey i am using Ublox neo 6m gps for some project and it has a U.fl connector and i dont have an antenna for it.I went to buy it and shopkeeper game me an ceramic internal antenna with a pin at its back[image]

like this,how can i add u.fl connector to this antenna?

Answer (score 1):

Find the antenna datasheet, design a pcb on which to properly mount the antenna following the design guidelines, add a section of 50 ohm transmission line from the antenna feed point to a u.fl connector footprint (again, properly designed based on the datasheet), send the design off to oshpark or similar, and solder it up. Or you can try to find a gps antenna that already has a u.fl connector, that would probably be a lot easier.